# Manipulate string in razor based on certain characters or length

Tags: c#, string, asp.net-core, razor

I am looking to manipulate a string in Razor syntax based on specific criteria. The string value will be an unknown length but some characters can help to establish when to split it up.

For example if I have "Health & Safety Courses" I would like to print out

```
<span>Health &</span>
<span>Safety Courses</span>
```

If I have "Safety courses\nat work" I would like to print out

```
<span>Safety courses</span>
<span>at work</span>
```

Notice the "\n" to create a new span element and close the old.

If there is a lengthy sentence like "Health and safety is our number one priority in the workplace"

I would like to print out

```
<span>Health and safety</span>
<span>Is our number one priority</span>
<span>in the workplace</span>
```

Notice when the character length is long it then splits it up into blocks.

I am fairly new to razor and unsure as to how tackle this. I have tried using Split() but that removed the character I am searching for and I have also tried to count the characters based on string length but this didn't work out too well either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the rules for defining a block? But more importantly, what are you trying to achieve? Is this so you can force where a sentence is allowed to word wrap?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace()` rather than `Split()`.Here is a demo：

html:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

js:

```
$(function () {
        var s = "Health & Safety Courses";
        s = "<span>" + s.replace("&", "&</span><span>") + "</span>";
        $("#myDiv").html(s);
    })
```

result:
[image]